# Implementing closestHit

Tags: directx

I am trying to re-create a function similar to direct x's mesh.Intersect(Vector3 rayPos, Vector3 rayDir, out IntersectInformation3 closestHit) function and I have succeeded in getting it to a point as shown in the series of codes below using my own Traingle.Intersect(Vector3D rayPos, Vector3D rayDir, out IntersectInformation3D closestHit). I have been able to populate the IntersectInformation3D class with all necessary information but one - Dist. I intend to use this as the source for obtaining the closestHit as shown in the code below, but it is not giving me a consistent result. Can anyone please look through that part of the code to tell me where I am getting it wrong. If there is any extra code needed, please let me know.

```
// Summary:
//     Describes the intersection of a ray and a triangle.
public class IntersectInformation3D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the IntersectInformation3D class.
    /// </summary>
    public IntersectInformation3D() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves or sets the distance along the ray where the intersection occurred.
    /// </summary>
    public float Dist { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves or sets the index of the triangle that intersected the ray.
    /// </summary>
    public int FaceIndex { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves or sets the index of the triangle that intersected the ray.
    /// </summary>
    public int TriangleIndex { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves or sets the barycentric coordinate within the triangle where the ray intersects.
    /// </summary>
    public float U { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves or sets the barycentric coordinate within the triangle where the
    /// ray intersects.
    /// </summary>
    public float V { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtains a string representation of the current instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>String that represents the object.</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Face={0}, Triangle={1}, tu={2}, tv={3}, Dist={4}", FaceIndex, TriangleIndex, Math.Round((decimal)U, 2), Math.Round((decimal)V, 2), Math.Round((decimal)Dist, 2));
    }
}

public class Vector3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public Vector3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double SumComponentSqrs()
    {
        return (this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y + this.Z * this.Z);
    }

    public double Magnitude
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(SumComponentSqrs());
        }
    }

    public Vector3D Normalize()
    {
        double magnitude = this.Magnitude;
        if (magnitude == 0)
        {
            return (new Vector3D()); //throw new DivideByZeroException("Can not normalize a vector when it's magnitude is zero");
        }
        else
        {
            return (new Vector3D(X, Y, Z) / magnitude);
        }
    }
}

public class Utility
{
    public static double Dot3(Vector3D p1, Vector3D p2)
    {
        return ((p1.X * p2.X) + (p1.Y * p2.Y) + (p1.Z * p2.Z));
    }

    public static Vector3D Cross3(Vector3D a, Vector3D b)
    {
        double outx = a.Y * b.Z - a.Z * b.Y;
        double outy = a.Z * b.X - a.X * b.Z;
        double outz = a.X * b.Y - a.Y * b.X;

        return new Vector3D(outx, outy, outz);
    }

    public static double modv(Vector3D v)
    {
        return System.Math.Sqrt(v.X * v.X + v.Y * v.Y + v.Z * v.Z);
    }
}

public class Triangle : Face
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the normal for this triangle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Vector3D object that represents the normal of this triangle</returns>
    public Vector3D GetNormal()
    {
        Vector3D p1 = VertexInformation.Vertex[0];
        Vector3D p2 = VertexInformation.Vertex[1];
        Vector3D p3 = VertexInformation.Vertex[2];

        Vector3D u = p2 - p1;
        Vector3D w = p3 - p1;

        Vector3D n = Utility.Cross3(u, w);

        return n.Normalize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for intersection between a ray and this triangle
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rayPos">A Vector3D structure that specifies the origin coordinate of the ray</param>
    /// <param name="rayDir">A Vector3D structure that specifies the direction of the ray</param>
    /// <returns> Intersection Information (when it exists) </returns>
    public bool Intersect(Vector3D rayPos, Vector3D rayDir, out IntersectInformation3D closestHit)
    {
        closestHit = new IntersectInformation3D();
        // Triangle vertices
        Vector3D V1 = VertexInformation.Vertex[0];
        Vector3D V2 = VertexInformation.Vertex[1];
        Vector3D V3 = VertexInformation.Vertex[2];

        //Find vectors for two edges sharing V1
        Vector3D e1 = V2 - V1; //Edge1
        Vector3D e2 = V3 - V1; //Edge2
        //Begin calculating determinant - also used to calculate u parameter
        Vector3D P = Utility.Cross3(rayDir, e2);
        //if determinant is near zero, ray lies in plane of triangle
        float det = (float)Utility.Dot3(e1, P);
        //NOT CULLING
        if (det > -float.Epsilon && det < float.Epsilon) return false;
        float inv_det = 1.0f / det;

        //calculate distance from V1 to ray origin
        Vector3D T = rayPos - V1;

        //Calculate u parameter and test bound
        float u = (float)Utility.Dot3(T, P) * inv_det;
        //The intersection lies outside of the triangle
        if (u < 0.0f || u > 1.0f) return false;

        //Prepare to test v parameter
        Vector3D Q = Utility.Cross3(T, e1);

        //Calculate V parameter and test bound
        float v = (float)Utility.Dot3(rayDir, Q) * inv_det;
        //The intersection lies outside of the triangle
        if (v < 0.0f || u + v > 1.0f) return false;

        float t = (float)Utility.Dot3(e2, Q) * inv_det;

        if (t > float.Epsilon)
        {
            Vector3D basePoint = new Vector3D();
            //ray intersection
            closestHit.U = u;
            closestHit.V = v;
            closestHit.Dist = DistToPoint(rayPos, out basePoint);
            return true;
        }

        // No hit, no win
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the distance between this triangle's intersect point
    /// with a ray at position P
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="P">A Vector3D structure that specifies the origin coordinate of the ray</param>
    /// <param name="B"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public float DistToPoint(Vector3D P, out Vector3D B)
    {
        Vector3D normal = GetNormal();
        Vector3D V0 = VertexInformation.Vertex[0];
        float sn = -(float)-Utility.Dot3(normal, (P - V0));
        float sd = (float)Utility.Dot3(normal, normal);
        float sb = sn / sd;

        B = P + sb * normal;
        return (float)Utility.modv(P - B);
    }
}

    public bool Intersect(Vector3D rayPos, Vector3D rayDir, out IntersectInformation3D closestHit)
    {
        bool result = false;

        int FaceIndex = 0;
        IList<IntersectInformation3D> intersectInfos = new List<IntersectInformation3D>();

        foreach (Face face in faces)
        {
            int TriangleIndex = 0;
            foreach (Triangle triangle in face.GetTriangles())
            {
                IntersectInformation3D intersectInfo = new IntersectInformation3D();
                bool tmp = triangle.Intersect(rayPos, rayDir, out intersectInfo);
                if (tmp)
                {
                    result = tmp;
                    intersectInfo.FaceIndex = FaceIndex;
                    intersectInfo.TriangleIndex = TriangleIndex;
                    intersectInfos.Add(intersectInfo);
                }
                TriangleIndex++;
            }
            FaceIndex++;
        }

        closestHit = new IntersectInformation3D();
        closestHit.Dist = float.MinValue;
        foreach (IntersectInformation3D intersectInfo in intersectInfos)
        {
            if (intersectInfo.Dist > closestHit.Dist)
                closestHit = intersectInfo;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to know the distance between the ray start point and the first vertex of the triangle? I think you need to first think again about what distance you would really like to calculate.

Comment: I don't want to know the distance between the ray start point and the 1st vertex. I want to know the distance between the ray start point and the point of intersection on the triangle. I am hoping that that will help me know which is the closest of all the hit triangles.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

If I understand you clearly, you want to calculate the distance between the start point of the ray and the intersection point. and these two points are the arguments of function DistToPoint. but why do you pass `basePoint` in the code below? what's this point for?

```
if (t > float.Epsilon)
{
    Vector3D basePoint = new Vector3D();
    //ray intersection
    closestHit.U = u;
    closestHit.V = v;
    closestHit.Dist = DistToPoint(rayPos, out basePoint);
    return true;
}
```

**Question 2:**

In the code below, what does `VertexInformation` do? and where it comes from?

```
public float DistToPoint(Vector3D P, out Vector3D B)
{
    Vector3D normal = GetNormal();
    Vector3D V0 = VertexInformation.Vertex[0];
    float sn = -(float)-Utility.Dot3(normal, (P - V0));
    float sd = (float)Utility.Dot3(normal, normal);
    float sb = sn / sd;

    B = P + sb * normal;
    return (float)Utility.modv(P - B);
}
```

I am not sure what above code do, but AFAIK, to calculate the distance between two 3d points P1 and P2, you can simply use the following formula.

[image]

You can calculate the intersection point in function `Intersect`, suppose you got u, v and t, then the point is `(1 - u - v)V0 + uV1 + vV2` where V0, V1 and V2 is the 3 points of the triangle. with this point and the start point of the ray, you can apply the formula about, that's just lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience, I really appreciate it. I guess I gathered something from your questions.

Yes to question 1, I got that algorithm from the net and I think basePoint is the point of intersection on the triangle. But from what you posted, I guess I'll try out what you said.

To question 2, I've edited the code sample above to include the usage for the intersection method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was in the code all along: `float t` is the distance I was looking for. It didn't seem to work earlier, probably because of a mistake I was making elsewhere.